# Nosetest overwrites xml output

Tags: python, nosetests

I am having problems with nosestests writing to the unittext xml file twice.

I have this python script

```
import unittest

class aa(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_aa(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


testlist = []

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(aa)
testlist.append(suite)

allSuites = unittest.TestSuite(testlist)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(allSuites)

print 'done'
```

The problem is if I run it like this

```
nosetests  --with-xunit -s --verbosity=2 test.py
```

I get this output

```
test_aa (test.aa) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
done
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

The problem is this writes to the nosetests.xml file twice. Is there any way to only make this run the test once?

The reason I need this is I have a unit test that basically runs fine the first time, then fails the second time and the xml file is getting overwritten with 0 tests run.

Cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running tests twice, once during import (line with `unittest.xx.run(allSuites)`), and second time with nose once it discovers `test_aa()` test. If you are intending to use nose, you do not have to run tests in the script - nose will act as a test runner for you.

You can run it once by running test with plain `python your_test.py` (not using nose), or by rewriting test to be something like and using your command as stated in question:

```
import unittest

class aa(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_aa(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this will not run on import, only when tests are running with unittest with python
    testlist = []

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(aa)
    testlist.append(suite)

    allSuites = unittest.TestSuite(testlist)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(allSuites)

    print 'done'
```